# Подсказки для функций в IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Использую XML-документацию в коде проекта, пример:

```
/// <summary>
/// Archive file or folder from target path
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool CreateZipFile(string path)
{
    ...
}
```

При работе внутри данного проекта подсказки IntelliSense отображаются нормально, но если проект скомпилировать отдельно и подключать в виде dll - подсказок нет.
Как исправить?

Comment: Xml-ка рядом с библиотекой лежит сформированная?

Comment: Спасибо ты натолкнул меня на ответ

Answer (score 3):

Нужно включить опцию XML documentation file в настройках проекта и следить чтобы сформированный XML-файл лежал рядом с библиотекой.